# Is disrespectiong the translated Quran a sin?

Tags: quran

I am a revert Muslim and I respect the Quran in whatever form the Quran is .I want to know for information is it a sin and God will curse those who disrespect the Quran (translated) form of Al Quran witch also we have to respect.I want some clarification on this. I consider the Quran the word of God my Quran is in English kept in a clean place.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your interesting/significant query, it ought to be remarked:

**Yes, undoubtedly, disrespecting the translated Qur'an is a sin, too (as well as its -Arabic- origin).** Why?

Since it is actually the words of Allah, so disrespecting for it, is equaled to disrespecting for Allah's words.

E.g., as a related similar instance which can help us to have a better perception in regards to the issue: It is said that it is haram (forbidden) to tough the name of Allah without Wudhu in any languages, so it demonstrates that the significant thing is its origin which is related to Allah even though it is in other languages.
Hence, based on my conclusion according to above-mentioned issues, it can be inferred that: there is no difference in respecting Quran in diverse languages (in the position of practice/doing)

---

Source:

[article.tebyan.net](https://article.tebyan.net/366038/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-)

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the words and Book of Allah, or trying to undermine their sanctity and respect, is blatant kufr (disbelief) and no one would dispute that.
Allah says :

***“If you ask them (about this), they declare: ‘We were only talking idly and joking.’ Say: ‘Was it at Allah, and His Ayaat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) and His Messenger that you were mocking?’***

***Make no excuse; you disbelieved after you had believed…”
[al-Tawbah 9:65-66]***

This ayah clearly states that those who mock Allah, His Signs or His Messenger are kaafirs (disbelievers). Simply making fun of them is apostasy from Islam (riddah), according to the consensus of the Muslims, even if the person did not really intend to mock them but was “only” joking or trying to be funny.

Source: http://web.archive.org/web/20150507080206/http://islamqa.info:80/en/12930 (Please refer following link fro more details)

Comment: This doesn't address the actual question, which is about the translation of the quran, which is men made!

Comment: "O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin" (49:12) https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/dont-make-assumptions-about-the-beliefs-of-any-user-by-just-reading-the-post-th  i'm trying to help you improve your answers and understand the stack exchange model

Comment: The meaning of the word Quran means recite Iqra in arabic the Quran was revealed to prophet Muhammmad by angel Gabriel orally in arabic it was only later that oral Quran became a book wriiten down by the companions of prophet so we shuold respect both the al Quran and the translated  Quran because the name of the oone true God is in both the Quran arabic and translated.

Comment: This is my view.